# how to overlay a grand-child absolute div inside a fixed grand parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 3 divs. Grand parent (fixed), parent (relative) and a child (absolute) ...

I want the child to overlay the grand parent.

Here is my code:

```css
.grand-parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: calc(50% - 250px);
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the child element visible outside the parent and grand parent divs?

Comment: remove `overflow` from `.grand-parent` or make `child`'s position into `fixed`...

Comment: @kukkuz Your solution worked. Thanks.